# Sha256 salted is there any chance to use rainbow tables to "decrypt" it?

Tags: hash, sha, rainbowtable

i want to ask is there any chance to use rainbow tables on salted hashes if we already know the salt. First of all i want to introduce the system of that hashes.

Each of this is computed using the SHA-256 hash of 3 distinct inputs.
First, is the server seed. This is a precomputed value generated some time in the past. Seeds are generated in a chain such that today's seed is the hash of tomorrow's seed.

seed 0 => seed 1 => seed 2 => seed 3

Next, the server seed is salted (scrambled) with the results of the New York Lottery's Take 5 game. Drawn daily at 11:21 pm EST, these results (0-padded) are appended to the server seed for use the following day.

Finally, each roll is salted with the unique round id ensuring a different hash each roll.

The round's hash is generated using SHA256("serverseed-lottery-roundid"). Taking the first 8 hex digits of the resulting hash and converting to decimal yields an integer from 0-4294967295. Taking modulo 15 yields the final roll in the range 0-14.

And i add you few examples with these seeds and salts chronologically:
Seeds:

1# 08659e6ef7759d68c4a4d8b214217394c5f2b1a539cc51cc5f89be1f55ab737b

2# 6d7ef31d654c30b2113019de67b0bc5bd400c41fc1d916937f2aee378772480c

3# 37e9469b09afca5a985170684d18ece4e881bea5d5f22af8df1049129351b976

Salts:

1# 0406161724

2# 1020273438

3# 0111293436

Number of seed refer to number of salt and 1# starts from 19.01.2016

At the end this is some php implementation with these inputs.

$seed = "39b7d32fcb743c244c569a56d6de4dc27577d6277d6cf155bdcba6d05befcb34";

$salt = "0422262831";

$round_id = "1";

$hash = hash("sha256",$seed."-".$salt."-".$round_id);

$roll = hexdec(substr($hash,0,8)) % 15;

echo "Round $round_id = $roll";

I would be grateful if you help me with these statement :)

Comment: Why not just use a cryptographic PRNG to obtain the seed?

Comment: These seeds were from 3 days ago i mean #1 was 19.01.2016 2# 20.01.. etc.

Comment: Can you clarify the method with cryptograpghic PRNG to obtain the seed ?

Comment: Weird you're so freaked out about this but you're using a salt anybody can obtain rather than generating a crypographically-safe random number for each thing you're hashing.

Comment: The main goal is to obtain the next seeds :)

Comment: @TomekKawka Add a language to the question. Just google "cryptographic PRNG <your_language>".

Comment: I mean reverse function to get tommorow's seeds :) will it be succesful to guess from seeds worked in the past ?